# Codificação errada no MySQL quando insiro através de AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, collation

Estou com dificuldade em encontrar uma solução para o meu problema. Resumidamente:

Envio dados para uma tabela, usando um ficheiro php que faz a querry, e uma chamada ajax que manda tudos os valores que preciso para o ficheiro php. Quando é inserido na tabela os acentos das palavras estão todos malucos. Se eu adicionar entradas para a tabela usando phpmyadmin não acontece este erro. Como posso resolver?

- Chamada AJAX:

  ```
  pageurl = 'http://estradasegura.pt/exames/testesDB.php';
                      //para consultar mais opcoes possiveis numa chamada ajax
                      //http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
                      $.ajax({

                          //url da pagina
                          url: pageurl,
                          //parametros a passar
                          data: dadosajax,
                          //tipo: POST ou GET
                          type: 'POST',
                          //cache
                          cache: false,
  ```
- Ficheiro PHP que liga ao MySQL:

  ```
  ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);

  $dbname = 'nomedabasededados';
  $username = 'meuusername';
  $password = 'ahahahaha';
  $servername = 'localhost';

  $pergunta = $_POST['pergunta']; 
  $resA = $_POST['resA'];   
  $resB = $_POST['resB'];
  $resC = $_POST['resC'];  
  $resD = $_POST['resD'];  
  $resE = $_POST['resE'];  
  $acertaram = intval($_POST['acertaram']); 
  $falharam = intval($_POST['falharam']);
  $dificuldade = intval($_POST['dificuldade']); 
  $resposta = intval($_POST['resposta']);  
  $imgSrc = $_POST['imgSrc'];


  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 


  $sql = " INSERT INTO perguntas ( pergunta, resA, resB, resC, resD, resE, acertaram, falharam, dificuldade, resposta, imgSrc )  VALUES ( ";

  $sql .= "'$pergunta', '$resA', '$resB', '$resC', '$resD', '$resE', '$acertaram', '$falharam', '$dificuldade', '$resposta', '$imgSrc' )" ;

   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  $conn->close();



  ?>
  ```

Comment: A tabela está em UTF8 ?

Comment: está em **utf8_general_ci**

Comment: Pode ser tres coisa, eu não mexo com mysqli(uso PDO), mas minha DSN no PDO fica utf8. Ou pode ser que seu header('content-type text/html charset=utf-8'). Também pode ser o arquivo, se seu arquivo está sendo salvo como utf8

Comment: **header('content-type text/html charset=utf-8')** usei isto antes de perguntar, mas como não mudou nada tirei do php. Quanto ao arquivo...não sei o que é pois fiz o meu primeiro código em php e mysql ontem e só tive umas horas para perceber minimamente como posso usar valores da/para a base de dados

Comment: Você usa notepad++ ?

Comment: sim, para editar PHP uso o notepad++, para editar o html e isso uso o Brackets (o filezilla abre php com notepad++ por defeito e estava nem aí para mudar)

Answer (score 0):

## Solucação 1


[image: Solução 1]

## Solucação 2


[image: Solução 2]

Ps: eu uso Sublime Text 3.
Preferencias -> Settings - Syntax Especific -> //no JSON faz assim:
"show_encoding": true

## Solução 3 - Notepad++


[image: notepad++ encoding]

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia usar o utf8_encode nos dados que precisar de caracteres na atribuição das variáveis post.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php.

Também pode tentar modificar o charset no seu html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

E no seu php

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

Comment: usei os três e tudo continua igual.

Comment: Dá uma olhada no banco, na tabela com mais cuidado. Tenta trocar o collate para utf8_unicode_ci. Tem uma discussão aqui (https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,187048,188748), dizendo que o utf8_general_ci , é mais simples, dá alguns problemas...

Comment: Já consegui resolver o problema, veja a resposta que coloquei. é muito parecida com a sua sugestão do `encode`, só que é outra função para  o mesmo efeito.

Comment: Sua solução converteu a string para ISO...

Comment: sim, mas funcionou :'D

Answer (score 0):

### Solução encontrada:

A solução que encontrei e que funcionou para o meu caso é a seguinte:

```
$pergunta = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $_POST['pergunta']);
```

Com esta alteração as strings são gravadas na base de dados sem nenhum tipo de erro dos caracteres. Para quem quiser saber mais sobre `iconv()` pode visitar [este](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.iconv.php) link.

Comment: Pelo comando que você deu a sua string saiu do tipo "ISO-8859-1"... Dá um utf8_decode e veja se o resultado é o mesmo...

Comment: confirmo que funciona exactamente da mesma maneira

Comment: Então o problema é o inverso! :D